# Bash: my output is on one line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cut, cat

I have this code that counts the occurrences of different college majors within the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
OUT=$( cat $file | cut -d',' -f3 | sort | uniq -c)
echo $OUT
```

That produces this output:

```
4 Computer Information Systems 2 Computer Science 2 History 1 Marketing 2 Social Studies
```

How do I get the output to look like this:

```
4 Computer Information Systems 
2 Computer Science
2 History
1 Marketing
2 Social Studies
```

With every major being on its own line?

This may seem like a silly question but I am very new to bash scripting. TIA for any help!

Comment: `echo "$OUT"`. Quotes are important.

Comment: And don't use all-caps names for your own variables -- those names are used by variables with meaning to the shell or operating system, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use.

Comment: Consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign the value to a variable, just this would do:

```
cut -d',' -f3 "$1" | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Enclose it within double quotes.

Comment: Yes, I have made the edit.